# Django Rest Framework - Serialize multiple models

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have two models, the default User model and a UserProfile model that extends the user model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='UserProfile')
    universidad = models.ForeignKey(Universidad, related_name ='universidad')
    group_admin = models.ManyToManyField(Group, related_name = 'group_admin')
```

I'm trying to obtain a user field that allows to GET, PUT and POST data with this format:

```
'username' = 'foo'
'password' = 'password'
'email' = 'a@b.com'
'universidad' = 'Harvard'
'group_admin' = [1] #list of groups id
```

I have used nested serializers but it's read only.

I also proved this solution, but i obtain a KeyError: 'universidad'.

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('url', 'username', 'password', 'email','universidad', 'group_admin')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `KeyError` occurs because you are trying to use the reverse relationship of `UserProfile` in the serializer. Reverse relationships aren't automatically included in HyperLinkedModelSerializers. See the [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations#reverse-relations) for more information and try:

fields = ('url', 'username', 'password', 'email','UserProfile__universidad', 'group_admin')

Comment: Hi @crhodes. Thanks for your answer but I am afraid that the error is still there. Now I obtain an UserProfile__universidad KeyError :S

Comment: Considering you want all the fields just use `UserProfile`